# CSS Blur in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, filter, internet-explorer-11, blur

I have been trying to get A css blur effect in IE 11 for hours and did not make any progress. I tried to use the following simple html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .blur{
                -ms-filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='50');
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <img src='http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120627075127/kirby/en/images/0/01/KDCol_Kirby_K64.png' class="blur" />
    </body>

</html>
```

I also tried just using the filter without the ms prefix. I saw that filter code on http://jsbin.com/ulufot/31/edit and even consulted the microsoft example http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/filter/blur.htm which does not work in my IE 11 on Win7. Do you have any ideas, what I could be doint wrong?

probably interesting if you are struggling too: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/hands-on-css3/hands-on_svg-filter-effects.htm

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to this blog (http://demosthenes.info/blog/534/Cross-browser-Image-Blur-with-CSS) the blur filter was dropped after IE9:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='3');
```

They did give a solution called StackBlur (using JavaScript and Canvases):

http://quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html

It is in the form of a javascript add-on downloadable from that site.

Comment: Could you please help in elaborate on how to use this script? There is not good tutorial for it.

Comment: Have you tried the example source code they provide? They also show three simple commands on the page - simple one-liners. Usage: stackBlurImage( sourceImageID, targetCanvasID, radius, blurAlphaChannel );
or: stackBlurCanvasRGBA( targetCanvasID, top_x, top_y, width, height, radius );
or: stackBlurCanvasRGB( targetCanvasID, top_x, top_y, width, height, radius );

Comment: Those are from the provided page: http://quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html

Comment: I don't understand those examples. What is blurAlphaChannel? I want to make a 'Div' Blur not image is this possible in IE 11 ?? Please help

Comment: RGB (red green blue) - Alpha: Transparency

Answer (score 10):

Here's a solution that works in IE10+ by using SVG:
https://jsfiddle.net/joegeringer/g97e26pa/8/

```
<svg width="230" height="120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="svgBlur">

  <filter id="svgBlurFilter">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" />
  </filter>

  <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" x="0" y="0" height="200" width="400" class="nonblurred" />

  <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" x="0" y="0" height="200" width="400" class="blurred" filter="url(#svgBlurFilter)" />

</svg>
```

Comment: @JeffClayton Those references are simply for demonstrating the code here, LoremPixel.com returns random images of the specified sizes.

Comment: This is terrific!

Comment: Bear in mind: you can't use this SVG image with linked image as background like `body { background-image: url(blurred.svg); }` even if you inline it via `url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,CODE") trick`, e.g. [this service](https://websemantics.uk/tools/svg-to-background-image-conversion/)