# Is there a way to blur backgrounds in IE11 using CSS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, css-filters

How do I support blur filter in IE11?

I tried `filter: blur(20px)` but that is not working

Comment: please add plunker

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filter: blur(1px); doesnt work in firefox, IE, and opera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803122/filter-blur1px-doesnt-work-in-firefox-ie-and-opera)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Blur in IE 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850100/css-blur-in-ie-11)