# How to fix: Full background image distorts in IE but works fine in chrome when using background-size: cover

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, distortion

Please have this CSS distortion I have been battling with cross browser:

https://dim.crservicesplc.ng/

Works fine in chrome but distorts in all others

***chrome***:
[image]

***IE, Edge, Firefox***
[image]

Assistance appreciated

Comment: It will be very helpful if you make jsfiddle.net

Comment: i simply shared the live link

Comment: @SohaibMohammed will that fix the left shift? blur is fine as it is expected to slightly distort the background. my issues is that the background in IE does not start from the same left position

Comment: I think you could make this using `SVG` filters using Snap.svg.js !

Comment: Just edit my answer and add Solution #2 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References:

> http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_rect.asp
>   http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_fegaussianblur.asp
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feGaussianBlur

You could control intensity of filter from `stdDeviation="15"` and `<rect style="opacity: 0.5;" />` and color of filter from `<rect style="fill: #333;>`

> Solution #1

```css
#home_main {
    margin: -30px;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url('https://dim.crservicesplc.ng/img/bg.jpg') !important;
/*            filter: blur(2px);*/
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

body {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

#home_content {
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-shadow: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans' !important;
    filter: initial !important;
    box-shadow: initial !important;
}

    #home_content h1 {
        color: #fff !important;
        font-size: 42px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #home_content p {
        color: #fff !important;
    }
```

```html
<div id="home_main" style="height: 613px;">
    <svg id="mySVG" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1131 591">
        <filter id="blurMe">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="15" />
        </filter>
      <rect filter="url(#blurMe)" width="1131" height="591" style="fill: #333; opacity: 0.5;  -ms-transform: scale(3, 3); -webkit-transform: scale(3, 3); 
transform: scale(3, 3); transform-origin: center;" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

> Solution #2

```css
#home_main {
    margin: -30px;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 0;
    /*background-image: url('https://dim.crservicesplc.ng/img/bg.jpg') !important;*/
/*            filter: blur(2px);*/
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

body {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

#home_content {
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-shadow: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans' !important;
    filter: initial !important;
    box-shadow: initial !important;
}

#home_content h1 {
    color: #fff !important;
    font-size: 42px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#home_content p {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="home_main" style="height: 613px;">
    <svg id="mySVG" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1131 591">
        <filter id="blurMe">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2" />
        </filter>
        <image filter="url(#blurMe)" xlink:href="https://dim.crservicesplc.ng/img/bg.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Please will these changes work in both IE and chrome?

Comment: Notice i have mentioned that the issue is the background image in IE does not start from the left=0 as it should. that is my main complain

Comment: Hmm! You are Ringht!

Comment: You could use `SVG` in the background also!

Comment: svg is not the issue pls. what i need is css correction to enable the bg not be offset in IE

Comment: Also in css-tricks: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/#browser-support

Comment: See this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850100/css-blur-in-ie-11 may be helpful!

Comment: I'm sorry I harass you due to SVG! but please see the support of SVG filters: http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-filters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123962/discussion-between-charles-okwuagwu-and-sohaib-mohammed).

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the margin-left property of your "#home_main" div, and then remove the paddings of your ".wrapper .wrapper-content" and "#page_wrapper" elements, to scale the background-image to the entire width of the window.

Hope this will help !