# How to apply a CSS 3 blur filter to a Text/image for Internet Explorer or IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, filter, css-filters

I tried, below filter in my **CSS** to blur text, But it works on Chrome, Mozilla & Safari only. I want this to work on IE 11 also. Can you suggest any alternative ?

I don't want to apply **StackBlur** solution as it will hinder performance tremendously , I have many places to blur in a single page.

```
.blurry-text {
text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00);
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
background: filter: url('/media/blur.svg#blur');
filter: blur(5px);
filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color=#333333), progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.MotionBlur(strength=0, direction=0), progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=5);
color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately blur is not sported on IE. Look [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=filter%3A%20blur). I think only solution is use [StackBlur](https://github.com/flozz/StackBlur)

Comment: @ciurciurek okay, thanks for your comment and link. But, if I use StackBlur implementation for my page where I need to apply this for more than 50 places and the number may grow. Therefore, I am really worrying about performance issue. I am thinking that after checking presence of IE engine, I may put either already blurry image on top of those area or apply StackBlur effect once and apply the same for all the area. Though, it would not be hundred percent accurate from blurry perspective. Any further opinion ?

Comment: I don't know what are You doing but maybe You can think about another logic  for IE. For example replace stocks by blured stocks. Unfortunately, I don't now specific answer for You question.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make blur filter using **SVG gaussian blur**! It is work with are [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-filters).
Control in intensity of blur from `stdDeviation="4"`

> [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/52fa55hr/)
>
> [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39640116/5688267)

```html
<div class="container" style="height: 613px;">
    <svg id="mySVG" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1131 591">
        <filter id="blurMe">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="4" />
        </filter>
        <image filter="url(#blurMe)" xlink:href="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/56d70b042b8dde104d998bda/t/56d9b7e827d4bdab535a3af8/1457109282817/kiddos.jpg?format=1500w" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```