# How to create shadow under image?

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I wanna create "flying" effect for images on hover with shadow under images. Important! Images can be of different widths (as well as shadows)
[image]

```css
body{
  padding: 50px;
}
.images{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.images__item{
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 30px;
  transition: .3s;
}
.images__item img{
  transition: .5s;
}
.images__item:hover {
  background: #FCF1F7;
}
.images__item:hover img{
  transform: translateY(-60px);
}
```

```html
<ul class="images">
  <li class="images__item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/130x200" alt="">
  </li>
  <li class="images__item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/220x250" alt="">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use a pseudo element and crank the blur up

Comment: @AndyHolmes could you pls give an example of such bluring?

Comment: Yeah give me a sec, I'll see if I can whip something up quickly

Comment: I see people are answering your question looking for rewards, but they can't be bothered upvoting you. It's a good question so I upvoted it, maybe others should do the same too. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've just written this to show you a proof of concept, please take the parts you need and use them inside your code.

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;  
}

.item .image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.item .image:after {
  width: calc(100% + 150px);
  height: 100px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -125px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  filter: blur(20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Here's a JSfiddle too - https://jsfiddle.net/a5Lxp1vy/

Comment: Thank you so much for help! One comment - IE11 doesn't support filter: blur :(

Comment: @someserj ah sorry! I don't support IE11 anymore so didn't think of that. This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850100/css-blur-in-ie-11

Answer (score -1):

Here is good example I am using here a div you can put image here:

```css
.box {
     position: relative;
     width: 400px;
     height: 250px;
     background-color: #fff;
  
     border-radius: 1%     1%     1%     1% /     1%     1%     1%     1%;
}
.box:after {
      position: absolute;
      width: 64%;
      height: 12%;
      left: 0%;
      border-radius: 50%;
      z-index: -1;
      bottom: 0%;
      content: "";
      box-shadow: 0 50px 24px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
.box>img{
  margin-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/eew9Te/html_How_to_create_shadow_under_image_Stack_Overflow.png" />
    </div>
```

Sample with your image cropped:

[image]