# Is there a way to blur react components on IE11?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, internet-explorer, blur

I'm aware of the fact that filters are not supported in IE 10-11, but is there a way to blur React Components in some way? I was looking for solutions, but didn't find anything useful. Is it even possible to blur entire components on IE11?

Comment: Yes, `filter: blur()` is not supported by IE 11. I don't know how your component is like, I think it could be better if you can provide [a code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about the component. Can you use svg? If so, you can use svg to blur. Svg blur can work well in IE 11. For detailed information, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850100/css-blur-in-ie-11/42562216#42562216) and [this blog](https://60devs.com/cross-browser-blur-effect.html).